# how to upgrade from rhel 7.2 to 7.3

Tags: rhel, upgrade

I have a minimal iso rhel7.3. I have transfered this iso to rhel7.2 server. The server has no internet.
Is it possible to upgrade from minimal rhel 7.3 iso ?

Comment: you "simply" mount iso file on a directory, and tell redhat (via /etc/yum.repos.d/dvd.repo file) where DVD is. I can't write as answer since I don't have exact repos.d syntax.

Comment: is possible with minimal iso 7.3?